# Reducing image resolution, issues

Tags: php, image, resolution

i have a site where users can upload images, and i have this function to reduce image resolution and preform alot of checks etc, works fine, except this 1 little bug i cant quite seem to figure out

$fixed_width is the width i want to declare as max allowed, but it is allowed to be lower, but for some reason, this if statement always triggers, and the image gets re-sized leaving a black box.

$width_orig = image width

$fixed_width = max allowed width, if higher, resize to that

$image_p = truecolor

$image = the current location of the img

```
if ($width_orig > $fixed_width) {
    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $fixed_width, $fixed_height, $width_orig, $height_orig); // reduce in width / height
} else {
    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width_orig, $height_orig, $width_orig, $height_orig); // leave as is
}
```

So why does it never pass, it resizes no matter what happens ?

Comment: Hard to say since you don't mention what your input values are.  Do a `var_dump()` to make sure they are what you think they are.  Also, make sure you are using some numeric type and not strings.

Answer (score 1):

The else block in your code does not make any sense. If you will not change the image, why copy-resample it?

Post the rest of your code to we see the way you are getting the original width.

Comment: Just so you know, short contributions asking for clarification are generally best as a comment, rather than an answer.

Comment: I am new here... The link to add a comment just showed to me in this answer, not in the original post...

Comment: Just went on a little research and discovered you have to have at least 50 of reputation to comment in other member answers, what is not my case yet...

Answer (score 0):

`$image_p` has fixed width and height. So when you copy something less, it has blank (black) background to fill the rest. Try just using `$image` instead (`else {$image_p = $image}`)